# Select item in a scrollview and change style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I created a vertical scrollview as below:

```
struct UserFeedView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        @State var selectedFilter: Filter?
        
        let filters = [
        Filter(name: "All"),
        Filter(name: "fil1"),
        Filter(name: "fil2"),
        Filter(name: "fil3"),
        ]

        VStack() {
            ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(filters) { filter in
                        Text(filter.name)
                            .font(.system(size: selectedFilter?.id == filter.id ? 30 : 20))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedFilter = filter
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .padding(.leading, 30)
            }
            .frame(height: 150)
            .onAppear {
               if let first = filters.first {
                   selectedFilter = first
               }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the font size of the selected item so the user can see what has been selected.

The goal is to :

When the user first access the screen, the first item is selected then when scrolling and selecting an item, the selected item has an increased size and bold compared to the other item.

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: You must not have `@State var selectedFilter: Filter?` and `let filters = [...]` inside the **body** of the view, put those outside, like in my answer. Let us know if my answer does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something simple like this:

In this example code, tapping on a `Filter` name in the scrollview, increases the
font size of the tapped `Filter` to **30**, leaving the other entries of size **20**.

The code also shows, that the first `Filter` is selected
(font size **30**) when the view first appear.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected: Filter?   // <-- here
    let filters = [
        Filter(name: "All"),
        Filter(name: "fil1"),
        Filter(name: "fil2"),
        Filter(name: "fil3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(filters) { filter in
                    Text(filter.name)
                        .bold(selected?.id == filter.id)  // <-- here
                        .font(.system(size: selected?.id == filter.id ? 30 : 20))  // <-- here
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selected = filter  // <-- here
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.leading, 30)
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
        .onAppear {
           if let first = filters.first {
               selected = first   // <-- here
           }
        } 
    }
}

struct Filter: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    var id: String { name }
}
```

EDIT-1

added `.bold(selected?.id == filter.id)` to have a bold appearance as well when selected.

Comment: thanks but it seems that the onGesture is not catching the click. When clicking on other name, the item is not changing its style

Comment: Is `my` code (as show above) not working for you, or is `your` code not working?
 Can you describe what system you are using and any relevent context code. I tested my answer on ios and mac catalyst, works very well for me.

Comment: I have updated my code above in description

Comment: You must not have `@State var selectedFilter: Filter?` and `let filters = [...]` inside the **body**, put them outside like in my answer. Does my answer work after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Filter` is `Identifiable`:

```
struct Filter: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    var id: String { name }
}
```

You can add a `@State` to your view that indicates which filter is selected.

```
// here I'm assuming "filters" is a global constant.
// if it is part of "self", then you would need to initialise it in onAppear
@State var selectedFilterId = filters[0].id
```

Then it is just a matter of showing different views depending on whether the filter is the selected one:

```
ForEach(filters) { filter in
    if filter.id == selectedFilterId {
        Text(filter.name)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .bold()
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedFilterId = filter.id
            }
    } else {
        Text(filter.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedFilterId = filter.id
            }
    }
}
```

You can extract the common `onTapGesture` by adding a `Group`:

```
Group {
    if filter.id == selectedFilterId {
        Text(filter.name)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .bold()
    } else {
        Text(filter.name)
    }
}.onTapGesture {
    selectedFilterId = filter.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper I tried the solution but the onTapGesture seems not working